# Passing parameters to Boxstarter via Install-BoxstarterPackage

Tags: powershell, chocolatey, boxstarter

When invoking a BoxStarter package, I use a powershell line such as:

```
Install-BoxstarterPackage -Package $script
```

I would like to pass some command line arguments into the package, but this does not seem to be supported.

Some relevant discussion:
https://github.com/mwrock/boxstarter/issues/5
An issue about a fix that does not seem to exist:
https://github.com/mwrock/boxstarter/issues/66

I ended up "cheating" and setting an environment variable before the package invocation like so:

```
$env:BoxstarterFoo = "Some Value"
Install-BoxstarterPackage -Package $script
```

Which makes $env:BoxstarterFoo available from within the package. This does not seem optimal. Is there a better way to pass information from an installation script into a boxstarter install right now, or is a workaround such as using environment variables required?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that is likely the best workaround currently available.

Comment: At least I'm not missing something obvious! Thanks for the great project.